# Userform showing only 1 out of 3 command buttons in excel

Tags: excel, vba, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, userform

I am new to VBA and I developed an excel file(.xlsb) in 32 bit. 
To make it compatible with 64 bit I have also added the Ptrsafe code in my modules and my code also compiles without any error in 64 bit. 
There is button on the sheet which shows userform with 3 command buttons. After adding the PtrSafe code, there are no errors but the userform shows only 1 command button out of 3 in 64 bit and I don't know why.
If somebody can help me with this, it would be great.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

    Me.Caption = DI_Name
    Dim lngWindow As Long, lFrmHdl As Long
    lFrmHdl = FindWindowA(vbNullString, Me.Caption)
    lngWindow = GetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, GWL_STYLE)
    Call SetWindowLong(lFrmHdl, -20, 500)
    Call DrawMenuBar(lFrmHdl)

     Dim AppXCenter, AppYCenter As Long
    AppXCenter = Application.Left + (Application.Width / 2)
    AppYCenter = Application.Top + (Application.Height / 2)
    With Me
        .StartUpPosition = 0
        .Top = AppYCenter - (Me.Height / 2)
        .Left = AppXCenter - (Me.Width / 2)
    End With
End Sub

#If VBA7 Then
    Const GWL_STYLE = -16
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "GetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function DrawMenuBar Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowA Lib "user32" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
#End If
```

And when I call the form, I have kept it as:

```
vbaform.Show vbModeLess
```

Comment: Why do you need such low-level code for buttons to show up on a form? Also I presume the `Declare` statements are actually at the very top of the module, because they would be illegal at the bottom like this. The code you provided has no indication of any buttons being created or drawn anywhere BTW

Comment: Yes the declare statements are at the very top of the module.